# FileWriter issue with \t

Tags: java, filewriter

I am trying to write a string to a batch file using Java `Filewriter` as following

```
fw.write("echo Default is: %SDK_ROOT%\\tools\\android-ndk-r10d\r\n");
```

It gives me the output as :

```
 echo Default is: %HEXAGON_SDK_ROOT%    ools\android-ndk-r10d
```

Its interpreting \tools as a tab space and ools. how to suppress the actual meaning of \t here ?

My desired output should be

```
echo            Default is: %HEXAGON_SDK_ROOT%\tools\android-ndk-r10d
```

what can I do here ?

Comment: You just need to escape the backslash, as you always do in a string literal: `"echo Default is: %SDK_ROOT%\\tools\\android-ndk-r10d\r\n");` This has nothing to do with `FileWriter` really - it's just a normal string literal.

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19762169/forward-slash-or-backslash

Answer (score 0):

Add `\` in front of each of your backslashes. They need to be duplicated inside string literals.