# list files of a Windows OS folder without using a double backslash file seperator

Tags: kotlin

i want to list files of a Windows OS folder. 
I want to use Windows file addresses in Kotlin without using a double backslash.
I do not want Kotlin to interpret the backslash here.

My best result for the moment you find at the end of my question.

Error: (3, 24) Kotlin: Illegal escape: '\ M' returns the following:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    var s: String = "G:\My Web Sites\"
    println(s)
}
```

I do not want to unmask the backslash with a backslash every time. I think it looks not good and can not easily copy back and forth.

works but is not pretty:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    var s: String = "G:\\My Web Sites\\"
    println(s)
}
```

walkaround:

Maybe I'll do it until I find another solution.

May there is a chance to switch the File.separator ?

of course this gaves me the same error, Because the replacement is too late:

```
import java.io.File
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    var s: String = "G:\My Web Sites\"
    val replace = s.replace('/', File.separatorChar);
    println(replace)
}
```

**best result:**

the best result i got is the following. it returns the correct file sting, but returns now files inside the folder.
it returns the correct string:
"G:\\My Web Sites\\"

```
import java.io.File

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    var s = """"G:\My Web Sites\"""
    println(s)
    s= s.replace("\\", "\\\\")
    println(s)
    File(s).walk().forEach  { println(it) }
}


private fun String.replace(regex: Regex, notMatched: (String) -> String, matched: (MatchResult) -> String): String {
//    its from https://github.com/http4k/http4k/blob/master/http4k-core/src/main/kotlin/org/http4k/core/UriTemplate.kt
    val matches = regex.findAll(this)
    val builder = StringBuilder()
    var position = 0
    for (matchResult in matches) {
        val before = substring(position, matchResult.range.start)
        if (before.isNotEmpty()) builder.append(notMatched(before))
        builder.append(matched(matchResult))
        position = matchResult.range.endInclusive + 1
    }
    val after = substring(position, length)
    if (after.isNotEmpty()) builder.append(notMatched(after))
    return builder.toString()
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use slash in your code, the JVM will automatically convert it to backslash on Windows (see [Forward slash or backslash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19762169/forward-slash-or-backslash)).

If you really like to use backslash, raw strings `"""` do the work and you don't need to replace it manually afterwards.

Comment: No, not here. Here only the variant with prepared string works (is shown below and commented out): https://github.com/sl5net/UnitTest4_g-IntelliSense-everywhere/blob/master/src/parse_AHK_helpfile.kt

Comment: works  https://github.com/sl5net/UnitTest4_g-IntelliSense-everywhere/commit/499caca7f1647b6f039bb14ae023df8a1021196f

Comment: is correct `"""G:\My Web Sites\""" is wrong """"G:\My Web Sites\"""`

Comment: \\ also seems to be correct http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/basic-types.html#characters