# Getting FileNotFoundException while running the job on jenkins, file path is showing incorrect

Tags: java, jenkins

I'm using an excel sheet to read some data for my framework and it is working properly locally but on Jenkins getting the below exception.

java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/ec2-user/workspace/sample-automation-suite\src\main\resources\NewData.xls (No such file or directory)

Using the filepath as :
String path = "\src\main\resources\NewData.xls";
String filePath = System.getProperty("user.dir") + path;

Can someone please suggest as what needs to be done to correct the file path it is reading here as /home/ec2-user/workspace/ in the start?

Comment: Either use forward slash always, or File.Seperator, or path..toAbsolutePath()

Kindly see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19762169/forward-slash-or-backslash

Comment: Thank you. I used forward slash and it started working.